# Macro to run when file is protected

Tags: excel, vba, plot

I did macro that creates a graph but need to make the file password protected.

Of course, when I protect the file, the macro will stop working.

I inserted the below into my code to unprotect the file, run the code, then protect the file again. As I the code is a function, I had to create two sub procedures, which is maybe the reason why the trick is not functioning.

Any idea how I can fix this?

```
Option Explicit
Sub protection()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "abc123"

End Sub

Function (here is my function code)

End Function

Sub protection2()
Worksheets("Sheet1").protect "abc123"

End Sub
```

Comment: You say you want the file to be protected but in your code you protect the sheet. Do you want the Workbook or the Worksheet protected?

Comment: Did you call the subs `protection` and `protection2` in your function?

Comment: If you need to make changes to a protected worksheet, just protect it with `UserInterfaceOnly`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to start one sub procedure to do the trick. My example unprotects your sheet, let the function do its magic and protects the sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub protection()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "abc123"

    Call Function (here may be values for your arguments)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").protect "abc123"
End Sub

Function (here may be prameters)

    the function code belongs here

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I have only one question regarding the call of the function. Am I supposed to insert the function name after "Call"? This is what I did but I receive the error message "Argument not optional"

Comment: I added the place for the arguments of the function. I recommend reading a bit about using functions in VBA. For example here: excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html

Answer (score 1):

On a protected sheet you can't changed cells which are locked. You may wan't to play around with the attached code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetSetup()
    Range("B3:C7").Locked = False
    Range("E3:F7").Locked = True   'This is default
End Sub

Sub Sample_ProtectedSheet()
    ClearValues
    ChangeAllValues_on_ProtectedSheet
    MsgBox ("Only values in ""B4:C7"" are set to ""yes""!")
End Sub

Sub Sample_UnprotectedSheet()
    ClearValues
    ChangeAllValues_on_UnprotectedSheet
    MsgBox ("All values set to ""yes""!")
End Sub


Function ChangeAllValues_on_UnprotectedSheet()
    Call Unprotect
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B4:C7").Value = "yes"
    Range("E4:F7").Value = "yes"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function ClearValues()
    Call Unprotect
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B4:C7").Value = ""
    Range("E4:F7").Value = ""
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function ChangeAllValues_on_ProtectedSheet()
    Call Protect
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B4:C7").Value = "yes"
    Range("E4:C7").Value = "yes"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub Protect()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect "abc123"
End Sub

Sub Unprotect()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "abc123"
End Sub
```

[image]